# General Directions for Drawing This Diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I was wondering if you can tell me which commands I should use to draw the various pieces with TikZ? I will write the code and adjust all the parameter, I would just like to know which commands are best to use for my picture. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Use `\coordinate` do define named points for the z and w series, also make a c series for the circle centers. `\fill (point) circle (radius);` to mark the point dot, can be combined with `node` to give text. `\draw (point) circle (radius);` to make the circles. To draw the two curves, you can look that up your self. There is nothing special with this image. Just start at one end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to draw this diagram is to use `decorations.markings` to set nodes along the curves, which one can draw e.g. with `[bend left]`. `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}` is a counter provided by that library which we can use here. Circles around subsets of these nodes can be drawn with the `fit` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[set marks/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark={between positions 0.2 and 0.8 step 0.2
 with {\node[bullet,label=90:{$#1_{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}}$}](#1\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence
 number}){};
        }}}}},bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt},
 cfit/.style={circle,draw,label=below right:#1}]
 \draw[set marks=z] (0,0) node [bullet,label={[name=l0]below:{$z_0=w_0$}},alias=w0] (z0){} 
 to[bend left=20] (5,4) node [bullet,label={[name=l5]above:{$z_5=w_5$}},alias=w5] (z5){} ;
 \draw[set marks=w] (0,0) to[bend right=20] (5,4);
 \node[cfit=$D_0$,fit=(l0) (z1) (w1)]{};
 \node[cfit=$D_1$,fit=(z2) (w2) (z1) (w1)]{};
 \node[cfit=$D_2$,fit=(z2) (w2) (z3) (w3)]{};
 \node[cfit=$D_3$,fit=(z4) (w4) (z3) (w3)]{};
 \node[cfit=$D_4$,fit=(z4) (w4) (l5)]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or without markings.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt},
 cfit/.style={circle,draw,label=below right:#1}]
 \draw (0,0) node [bullet,label={[name=l0]below:{$z_0=w_0$}},alias=w0] {}
  to[bend left=20] 
  node[pos=0.2,bullet,label=120:$z_1$] (z1){} 
  node[pos=0.4,bullet,label=-20:$z_2$] (z2){} 
  node[pos=0.6,bullet,label=-20:$z_3$] (z3){} 
  node[pos=0.8,bullet,label=-90:$z_4$] (z4){} 
  (5,4) node [bullet,label={[name=l5]above:{$z_5=w_5$}},alias=w5] (z5){} ;
 \draw (w0) to[bend right=20] 
 node[pos=0.2,bullet,label=90:$w_1$] (w1){} 
  node[pos=0.4,bullet,label=90:$w_2$] (w2){} 
  node[pos=0.6,bullet,label=90:$w_3$] (w3){} 
  node[pos=0.8,bullet,label=90:$w_4$] (w4){} (w5);
 \node[cfit=$D_0$,fit=(l0) (z1) (w1)]{};
 \node[cfit=$D_1$,fit=(z2) (w2) (z1) (w1)]{};
 \node[cfit=$D_2$,fit=(z2) (w2) (z3) (w3)]{};
 \node[cfit=$D_3$,fit=(z4) (w4) (z3) (w3)]{};
 \node[cfit=$D_4$,fit=(z4) (w4) (l5)]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks a lot!

Comment: I would like to incorporate this drawing into another file, so my document class is "book". Would you be able to tell me what change I have to make based on that?

Comment: @Ovi You could just include the pdf or use `\includestandalone`. (I have to leave now for a bit.)

Comment: Okay thank you again for the help!